# Service discovery with Percona XtraDB Cluster docker image

Tags: docker, percona-xtradb-cluster

I'd like to set up a Percona XtraDB Cluster 
[using this Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/percona/percona-xtradb-cluster). The documentation for the Docker image assumes the use of the etcd discovery service.

My question is this: Doesn't Docker ship with a built in service discovery (i.e. DNS server), makeing the use of etcd redundant? Or are there use cases where the build in service discovery is still needed? 
How would one typically go about using the build in service discovery for muliti host setups?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, Docker discovery service is only available on docker-swarm-based images/setups. This PXC Docker image is not swarm capable and thus uses an external discovery service. Running etcd is completely optional, as stated on the Docker image README. You can manually specify each other node when starting multiple nodes.

Comment: Thanks for our input! If I'm not mistaking, I get an automatic discovery service for services initiated from the same docker-compose file. For cross host discovery, I'll have to look into swarm (if supported) or an external service.